# sharing swap partition on network

Tags: networking, swap, nfs

I have an **HPC** including a server and about 20 **diskless** computing nodes. The server has a swap partition. I wonder if I could use this swap partition over network (ie. using **NFS**) to be used by computing nodes. I know this would cause serious speed reduction, but as nodes need small amount of swap for just some seconds, it worth to use this strange type of swapping.

P.S: nodes don't have HDD and they have the maximum supported memory(RAM).

P.S: Here:`http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Network-boot-HOWTO/x542.html`, it is said that I can do it for one remote workstation, but it doesn't say anything about having many workstations simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

you shall get an error like this, cause kernel needs to write to swap-file directly

```
  swapon: /mnt/shady/swapfile: swapon failed: Invalid argument
```

It's not possible to directly write to an NFS mount without going through the file-system you might be able to use i SCSI to do this, but the real question is whether it's worth it at all.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but as I searched, I can use swap partition over NFS(`http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Network-boot-HOWTO/x542.html`), but only for one remote system. As I mentioned, I have a number of computing node and I wonder if I can use only one swap space shared for all of them.

Comment: wow fascinating stuff as i said nfs swap cant be done unless that patch,other one with nbd protocol i have to try this thanks for the link, amazing stuff

Answer (score 0):

No you can not share a swap partition (or a swap file) between different active hosts. Linux' paging is not programmed in a way that expects that the swap partition is accessed concurrently from different systems.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing a swap partition between more than one concurrently running system is an exceedingly bad idea. The system swaps memory pages on and off this area. Consider what would happen if system A swaps out some pages, system B also does this with no knowledge of system A, System A retrieves it's pages (mangled by system B).

[The space can be shared](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5656/are-there-any-side-effects-when-two-distros-share-a-swap-partition) **if** you can guarantee that only one OS will use it at  a time, but that doesn't appear to be your use case. If the nodes have the maximum supported memory, the real question is [do I need swap at all?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/190398/do-i-need-swap-space-if-i-have-more-than-enough-amount-of-ram/190534#190534)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sharing the RAM of another machine via a swap over NBD

### host/server

Setup ramfs (if needed, if not just skip to nbd)

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/ram
sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=16G tmpfs /mnt/ram
```

Config file `/etc/nbd-server/config`:

```
[generic]
  user = nbd
  group = nbd
[swap]
  exportname = /mnt/ram/swap
  copyonwrite = false
  prerun = truncate -s 16G /mnt/ram/swap && mkswap /mnt/ram/swap
```

Start NBD

```
sudo systemctl start nbd
```

### client

```
sudo nbd-client 192.168.1.3 -name swap /dev/nbd0
sudo swapon /dev/nbd0
```